# What the RequestContext parameter in GetControllerInstance method of DefaultControllerFactory is for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I stumbled upon this method

```
protected internal virtual IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404,
                                    String.Format(
                                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                        MvcResources.DefaultControllerFactory_NoControllerFound,
                                        requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    MvcResources.DefaultControllerFactory_TypeDoesNotSubclassControllerBase,
                    controllerType),
                "controllerType");
        }
        return ControllerActivator.Create(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
```

and I'm wondering what the requestContext parameter is for since it seems it's never used. It's passed to ControllerActivator.Create but it never really used there either:

```
public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                return (IController)(_resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType) ?? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    String.Format(
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        MvcResources.DefaultControllerFactory_ErrorCreatingController,
                        controllerType),
                    ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `ControllerFactory` is to create `Controller` instances on demand. In order for it to be able to determine the appropriate `Controller` type it **may** need the RequestContext data.

Now, the `DefaultControllerFactory` (which is the default Factory) is indeed using the `RequestContext` only to throw the `Http 404 Not Found` exception (when needed), but other Controller Factories (that have to implement `IControllerFactory`) may use it.

For example, the `UnityControllerFactory` ([source](https://raw.github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/master/src/MvcContrib.Unity/UnityControllerFactory.cs)):

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext context, string controllerName)
        {
            Type type = GetControllerType(context, controllerName);

            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find a controller with the name {0}", controllerName));
            }

            IUnityContainer container = GetContainer(context);
            return (IController)container.Resolve(type);
        }

        protected virtual IUnityContainer GetContainer(RequestContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            var unityContainerAccessor = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as IUnityContainerAccessor;
            if (unityContainerAccessor == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "You must extend the HttpApplication in your web project and implement the IContainerAccessor to properly expose your container instance");
            }

            IUnityContainer container = unityContainerAccessor.Container;
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The container seems to be unavailable in your HttpApplication subclass");
            }

            return container;
        }
```