# Can I use DefaultControllerFactory after setting my Controller factory to a custom controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement a custom ControllerFactory as:

```
public class TodoController : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {


        if (controllerName == "Tasks")
        {
            return new TasksController(new TaskContext());
        }
        return base.CreateController(requestContext,controllerName);
    }
}
```

and 
`ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new TodoController());`

I keep getting exception on all routes except the one which invokes TasksController. The exception is:

> The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

I have seen other ways to implement a custom controller as mentioned in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i) using reflection to instantiate the controller for all *other* requests.

But I am confused that why I can't call the DefaultControllerFactory to instantiate the controller?

Answer (score 0):

`TaskContext()` probably doesnt have the `RequestContext` available. 
The following link may help in explaining. [Controller Creation via Activator..CreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587612/what-the-requestcontext-parameter-in-getcontrollerinstance-method-of-defaultcont)

Here is a quote "... *the DefaultControllerFactory (which is the default Factory) is indeed using the RequestContext only to throw the Http 404 Not Found exception (when needed), but other Controller Factories (that have to implement IControllerFactory) may use it*."

Comment: Thanks for your Answer . TaskContext should have been named TaskDBContext() . Its is a DB Context class and I don't think  it needs RequestContext. The link you pointed explains as to why RequestContext is required in DefaultControllerFactory .Your link has encouraged me to look for source of DefaultControllerFactory . Maybe will find something there.